# Null or terminator canary

Tags: c, gcc, ssp

Can I force the gcc to use a null canary or terminator canary, when SSP is enabled, instead of random canary?  If so, how?

Comment: Why would you want to use a canary that can easily be guessed by an attacker, and which therefore provides you with minimum protection?

Comment: Which concept is it not to be able to detect when one forget to take into account the NUL terminating a string?

Comment: I think that the question isn't the reason to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hack [`__guard_setup` function (libssp)](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/tags/gcc_4_3_2_release/libssp/ssp.c?view=markup)